# neural network training unsuccessful

Tags: networking

I am trying to predict football results using neuroph neural networks, I have tried various multi perceptron networks with different numbers of hidden neurons and can never get a low enough network error rate for the training to be successful.
The data in my training set is:
home team id, team rating, home win %, attackers rating, midfield rating, defence rating, away team id  team rating, away win %, attackers rating, midfield rating, defence rating,
output is 1 0 0 for home win 0 1 0 for draw 0 0 1 for away win.
The team ids are binary e.g. 0 0 0 0 1 - 1 1 1 1 1.
Is this data suitible for the network to train successfully?

Comment: Interesting project, but what is your programming question?

Comment: weather my input data is suitble for the network as my training is unsuccessful all the time

Comment: Ah.  Well then, I suspect the best answer to your question as asked would be ... No, it's not.  If you have a question about your code, though, please feel free to [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23090209/edit) and add the code you need help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should omit the ids. Neural networks return similar results for similar inputs and ids are therefore confusing.

Another problem is that multilayer perceptrons are not suitable for prediction. You should try a recurrent neural network, for instance [The Hebian network](http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/tutorials/Hebbian.html).

You should also try to map all inputs to the interval (0,1). Also try to experiment with diffeent ways of inputting data. For instance, try putting in difference of home win % and away win %.

Comment: thanks for the help it has gave me a better idea, what if the difference between the win percentages calculate to a minus value

Comment: Inputs can be negative, interval (0,1) is not a rule. You could still map it to (0,1) interval by inputting (x/2) + 0.5, for x = home_win% - away_win%, but neural network should deal with it. Good luck!